# Universal links for Facebook Page Manager iOs

Tags: ios, facebook, deep-linking, url-scheme

Does anyone know universal links for this app "Facebook Page Manager"? I searched the internet and found only this `fb://` but this is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I found them:

`fb-pma-diode://
 fb-pma://`